# Exporting an HBase table which is larger than the available HDFS space?

Tags: hadoop

I have a 1TB hbase table which I need to export. Unfortunately I only have 600GB free in HDFS, so I was hoping to export it to a mounted file share.

I've learned that the hbase export can only export to HDFS. Due to the above constraints I lack the space to do so.

Is there any way I can export the data of this table without increasing the available HDFS space?

Comment: You can't export some (say 1/4 at a time), then compress that (repeat until done...)?

Comment: To my (limited) knowledge, there aren't any flags for export that would allow me to do perform it in portions.

Comment: Sorry - it was just a thought - I know nothing about HDFS - however, it is curious (to me anyway) that useful data can't be partitioned? But, as I said, I'm not an expert in this area.